# How to develop custom metric with one class priority Keras

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

I tried like this. I get InvalidArgumentError, but I assume I am doing this completely wrong, I just don't know how to implement in in Tensorflow.

```
def correct_prediction(self, y_true, y_pred):

        y_true = K.get_value(y_true)
        y_pred = K.get_value(y_pred)

        score = 0

        for pred, true in zip(y_pred, y_true):

            if pred == 1 and true == 1:
                score += 100

            elif pred == 1 and true != 1:
                score -= 100

            elif pred == 0 and true == 0:
                score += 1

            elif pred == 0 and true != 0:
                score -= 1

            elif pred == 2 and true == 2:
                score += 1

            elif pred == 2 and true != 2:
                score -= 1

        print('score:', score)
        score = tf.cast(score, tf.float32)
        return K.variable(score)
```

Comment: See custom loss function in keras.